# Rigidbody2D to go through Box Collider 2D

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a scoring system for a game that I am making; it's a remake of Flappy Bird.

The issue I am having is, I have set up a sprite with a rigidbody2d and a box collider as the score; I am trying to make it so that when the character passes through that sprite; it will add one to the score however when the character attempts to go through it, it just get's pushed back to the other side of the screen.

This is because of the box collider of course but I am not sure of any other way of doing this without this method. Here is the code which detects if the character hits the pipe or the score line:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D hit) {
   if(hit.transform.gameObject.name == "Pipe(Clone)") {
      die();
      Debug.Log("hit");
   }
   if (hit.transform.gameObject.name == "Score(Clone)") {
      Debug.Log("Score");
   }
}
```

Everything logs perfectly fine however the problem is that the bird just faceplants into the score line which isn't what is supposed to happen, please try to help or advise what I should do with this.

P.S. I am a novice programmer; I sort of know what I am doing however not really good at debugging things and fixing them, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the "Is Trigger" on your Bird object collider in editor. And use:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
     if (col.transform.name == "Score")
           Score++;
 }
```

In the bird object script.